# What is the difference between the interjections "ĝuste" and "prave"?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

I understand the difference between *ĝusti* and *pravi*.

> *Tio ĝustas* - that is right, that is correct
>
> *Vi pravas* - you are right, what you are saying saying is correct

But what about when the adverb-forms are used as interjections? When somebody is speaking, I can exclaim "*Ĝuste!*" or "*Prave!*". Can they be used interchangably? Or are there different situations where one or the other is better?

Comment: Please help me with the tags on this one.

Comment: The tag you use is fine since you are asking how to use two words. I have just added a tag since the question is asking about two adverbs.

Answer (score 12):

They are as interchangable as *ĝusta* and *prava*. As you hinted at, *ĝusta* refers to being "correct" in the sense of being "appropriate" while *prava* refers to being "correct" in the sense of being "true":

- ĝusta: Precize konforma al regulo, leĝo, destiniteco; Precize konforma al la cirkonstancoj, al la intencata celo; Tia, ke ĝi liveras informojn verajn
- prava: Havanta opinion konforman al la vero; Konforma al la vero

So, if someone states a correct fact, I would say *prave*, because the fact they stated is true (*konforma al la vero*). If someone shows me a translated sentence that is grammatically correct, I would say *ĝuste*, because it conforms to the rules of the language, and it would be odd to say that it is "true". In many cases, however, they are ambiguous if not interchangeable and most likely no one will get confused if you use one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

You can say i.e. "ĝuste tion", but not "prave tion".
I guess that "ĝuste" is used for objects and "prave" for persons, ideas, opinions etc.
But I'm not sure if this is a general rule.